# Which blackberry device will support OS 4, 5 and 6?

Tags: blackberry, mobile

Hi i need to buy a blackberry to test my applications. I want to buy a device which supports more OS versions (I will be happy if it supports all versions). Which Blackberry device will supports OS 4, 5 and 6 ?? can any one help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlackBerry devices only ever tend to support two major OS releases so you're out of luck trying to run all three on any one handset.

If you can only buy one handset then I suggest you buy one the later ones. This is because a phone running OS7 can also run applications written for OS6,5,4.5 etc

There are still quirks you will run into, but even the two phones running the same OS may function differently. E.g. if the internal storage is based on a microsd card or not.

RIM has done an excellent job of providing simulators for every type of phone so in the first instance you can download and try these.

If you run into a problem that's specific to one device and you cannot replicate it on the simulator then another option is to subscribe to services like [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/)

In my opinion if you are designing a UI it's essential to be able to test touchscreen and trackball devices. Therefore I suggest the Torch or Bold 9900 as be good candidates for you as they can do both.

Comment: i dint mention about installing 2 or 3 os in same device.. i just expect that versions should support to that device.. will the device contains OS 7 support the lower version OS ?

Comment: No BlackBerry handset supports all 3 of the OS's you mentioned. Also There is no way to install more than one OS at once, you have to completely remove one to install another. I said OS7 devices can run applications written for older OS versions, I didn't say they can run the older OS.

Comment: i understood that. If i want to run my app in OS 7 device means, should i put a separate build for that or my OS5 version build work on it ?

Comment: You can run an application written for OS5 on an OS7 phone. You can also run an application written for OS's 4.5, 5 and 6 on an OS7 phone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no BlackBerry device that supports all versions: OS 4.x and OS 5 and OS 6.

Comment: I am not aware about such devices, which support 5 and 6. Curve and Storm devices support 4.x (4.5, 4.6 for Curves and 4.7 for Storms) and 5.0.

Comment: most of the clients are expecting OS 5,6 and 7.. commercial projects :-)

Comment: The curve 8530 can be upgraded from 5 to 6, at least for verizon

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention Bold devices.